# Is there any available online interpreter solution

Tags: python, web-services

Since I had no other chance to solve a particular problem, I wrote a domain specific language (an it is in my own language, Turkish) in Python.

I need to test it as much as I can. That's why I need to prepare an online interpreter, so my friends could help me testing.

Should I hack a chat example of Tornado or something, or is there any readily available project that fits in that purpose?

Process should be: 
1. write code
2. run it 
3. see output
4. interact with currently running code

Comment: http://repl.it/languages/Python

Comment: Can I download the server side code? EDIT: I JUST SAW the source code link!!

Comment: What do you mean with #4? That programs are interactive?

Comment: Yes. It's like SCXML. You should send signals, it will respond.

Comment: [Codecademy Labs](http://labs.codecademy.com/) is another option.

Answer (score 0):

There are websites that have these features already.
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/ or 
http://www.wakari.io/